# XSLT Transformation doubt

Tags: xslt

I want to write an xslt to transform one xml file to another. The source XML file is like the following

```
<orgs>
<organization revenue="10000">
  <name>foo</name>
</organization>
<organization parent="foo">
 <name>foo2</name>
</organization>
<organization parent="foo2">
 <name>foo3</name>
</organization>
</orgs>
```

The output xml should be as follows

```
<orgo>
<organization revenue="10000">
 <name>foo</name>
 <organization>
  <name>foo2</name>
  <organization><name>foo3</name></organization>
 </organization>
</organization>
</orgo>
```

So far i've tried writing the xsl as follows
[image: xslt]

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for two different, complete and short solutions. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<orgs>
    <organization revenue="10000">
        <name>foo</name>
    </organization>
    <organization parent="foo">
        <name>foo2</name>
    </organization>
    <organization parent="foo2">
        <name>foo3</name>
    </organization>
</orgs>
```

**produces the wanted, correct output**:

```
<orgs>
   <organization>
      <name>foo</name>
      <organization>
         <name>foo2</name>
         <organization>
            <name>foo3</name>
         </organization>
      </organization>
   </organization>
</orgs>
```

**In case the order of `<organization>` elements is random, like in the following XML document**:

```
<orgs>
    <organization parent="foo2">
        <name>foo3</name>
    </organization>
    <organization parent="foo">
        <name>foo2</name>
    </organization>
    <organization revenue="10000">
        <name>foo</name>
    </organization>
</orgs>
```

**this transformation produces the wanted result**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="organization[not(@parent)]"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="organization">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="../organization[@parent=current()/name]"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1 This is a good answer. Also, whenever there is cross reference, keys are a good choice.